# How to detect which files which have been added to a directory over time?

Tags: python

I am reading a directory of 180 files and everyday a file is added. I need to first read all files for today, but tomorrow I need to run to code and have it not return any old files that have already been read. Is there anyway to do this? Here is my current loop to iterate and read through all the files.

```
#iterating through all the files
for file in os.listdir():
    #check if file is in .ls format or not
    if file.endswith(".ls"):
        filepath = f"{path}\{file}"
        #calling the read function
        axisMonitorAverage(filepath)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have always to iterate throught all the files to check the date, for example, or confront the file you've already read yesterday

Comment: So would I need two seperate codes? One for uploading the data today and then one tomorrow that would only do the new daily upload?

Comment: If the files have `timestamp`  prob. you could put them in a sorted `list` as being processed.  Next day just check the new file.  Or you could consider `zip` older file, so there is only one fresh one from current day.

Comment: @Jon no, you can use the same code but you have to store some sort of information about the already read file. Like "start reading from"

Comment: Seems fairly obvious you're going to have to save the list of files somewhere so you have something to compare with what's currently in the directory in order to detect changes.

Comment: @DanielHao so creating a list of all the past dates and then using a statement when at the end of the loop to say if (these dates) are read ignore?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the file names into a `set` and save it to file (e.g with the pickle module), then check if the filename is not in the set

```
import os
import pickle

path = os.curdir
processed = None

try:
    with open('processed.txt', 'rb') as f:
        processed = pickle.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    # first run
    processed = set()

for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".ls"):
        filepath = f"{path}\{file}"
        
        #calling the read function
        axisMonitorAverage(filepath)

        # add the file to the set of processed files
        processed.add(file)

with open('processed.txt', 'wb') as f:
   pickle.dump(processed, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
from glob import glob

# check if the parsed.txt file exists if not create empty list
if os.path.exists('parsed.txt'):
    with open('parsed.txt', 'r') as f:
        parsed_files = f.read().splitlines()
else:
    parsed_files = []

# iterating through all the .ls files
for filepath in glob("*.ls"):
    # check if file is not parsed
    if filepath not in parsed_files:
        # calling the read function
        axisMonitorAverage(filepath)
        # adding to the parsed_files
        parsed_files.append(filepath)

# saving the new parsed_files list
with open('parsed.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(parsed_files))
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72575994/how-to-detect-which-files-which-have-been-added-to-a-directory-over-time#comment128203397_72575994), you'd need to store the directory's contents somewhere in order to compare what's currently in it to what was there previously to determine what's changed.

Below is code illustrating how to detect changes by periodically polling the directory — you should be able to figure out how to save and reload the contents between separate executions yourself (probably in a file).

```
from pathlib import Path
import time


PATH_TO_WATCH = Path('./watched_dir')
SUFFIX = '.ls'
PATTERN = '*' + SUFFIX

before = set(PATH_TO_WATCH.glob(PATTERN))
print('Initial files:', '.join(f.name for f in before))

# Poll directory and watch for changes.
while True:
    time.sleep(5)

    after = set(PATH_TO_WATCH.glob(PATTERN))
    added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
#    removed = [f for f in before if not f in after]

    if added:
        print('Added: ', ', '.join(f.name for f in added))
#    if removed:
#        print('Removed: ', ', '.join(f.name for f in removed))

    # Process any files that were added.
    for filepath in added:
        axisMonitorAverage(filepath.resolve())

    before = after
```